# How can I add an additional row and column to an array?

Tags: python

I need to add a column and a row to an existing Numpy array at a defined position.

Comment: This needs a little more information

Comment: what kind of an array? list of lists, array.array or numpy.array?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I assume your column and rows are just a list of lists?

That is, you have the following?

```
L = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]]
```

To add another row, use the append method of a list.

```
L.append([7,8,9])
```

giving

```
L = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]]
```

To add another column, you would have to loop over each row. An easy way to do this is with a list comprehension.

```
L = [x + [0] for x in L]
```

giving

```
L = [[1,2,3,0],
     [4,5,6,0]]
```

Comment: and to convert that to array just do array(lst) ?

Comment: That should work. There's probably a better way to do this with numpy, but your original question did not specify such.

Comment: `np.append` takes an `axis` argument specifying the dimension to append; so the way described for adding a new column is discourage because it is not numpy-optimized.

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to do this in numpy, but not all of them let you add the row/column to the target array at *any* location (e.g., append only allows addition after the last row/column). If you want a single method/function to append either a row or column at any position in a target array, i would go with '**insert**':

```
T = NP.random.randint(0, 10, 20).reshape(5, 4)
c = NP.random.randint(0, 10, 5)
r = NP.random.randint(0, 10, 4)
# add a column to T, at the front:
NP.insert(T, 0, c, axis=1)
# add a column to T, at the end:
NP.insert(T, 4, c, axis=1)
# add a row to T between the first two rows:
NP.insert(T, 2, r, axis=0)
```

Comment: I am using you solution after a decade and it works perfect for my need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest sympy `Matrix` object to do it:

```
a = [[ 2,   1,  180],
     [ 1,   3,  300],
     [-1,  -4,    0]]

b = [[1,0],
     [0,0],
     [0,1]]
```

```
import sympy as sp

a = sp.Matrix(a).col_insert(-2, sp.Matrix(b))
a.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[2, 1, 0, 1, 180], 
 [1, 0, 0, 3, 300], 
 [-1, 0, 1, -4, 0]]
```

And to continue with a Numpy array, you can use `np.asarray(a)` instead of `a.tolist()` (assuming you have imported Numpy as `np`)