# Append some columns to a list of list matrix

Tags: python, list, append

I have some troubles in merging two list of lists to one. I think there is a simple solution, but I'm stuck for hours.

My two list of lists are for example:

```
a=[['1','2'],['3','4']]
b=[['5','6'],['7','8']]
```

And what I try to get is:

```
c=[['1','2','5','6'],['3','4','7','8']]
```

But I don't know how many rows and columns the lists have.

I tried to use the `zip` command but it produced something like:

```
[(['1','2'],['5','6']),(['3','4'],['7','8'])]
```

Thanks very much for any help on this issue!!!

Maybe something like [How can I add an additional row and column to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002415/how-can-i-add-an-additional-row-and-column-to-an-array) would work but I suppose there is an simpler solution.

Comment: Any specific programming language?

Comment: oh, sorry, I'm writing in python. Thanks for the fast answers!
@leppie could you help me with the exact formatting? I couldn't get it work.

Comment: @MatthiasLa: Sorry, I dont know python at all ;p My answer was Scheme. (but those look like vectors/arrays, and not lists, but then, I dont know python at all)

Comment: @leppie: Thanks anyway, I appreciate any help!
Furthermore I think that in [AddColumn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002415/how-can-i-add-an-additional-row-and-column-to-an-array) something quite similar to my problem is described. But I think there has to be a simpler way then to split up every row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> a=[['1','2'],['3','4']]
>>> b=[['5','6'],['7','8']]
>>> [x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[['1', '2', '5', '6'], ['3', '4', '7', '8']]
```

Comment: ...Wow it was that simple. Here I was using all these crazy functions and you just appear with this. +1 to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
[sum(ai_bi, []) for ai_bi in zip(a, b)]
```

which scales to n lists of lists :

```
L = (a, b, ...)
[sum(el, []) for el in zip(*L)]
```

Comment: yeah if you are adding 2 items just use `+` (no need for sum here)

Answer (score 0):

If the two lists are of the same length, you could use a simple loop:

```
listone = [['1','2'],['3','4']]
listtwo = [['5','6'],['7','8']]
newlist = []

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    newlist.append(listone[i] + listtwo[i])

print(newlist)
[['1','2','5','6'],['3','4','7','8']]
```

Answer (score -1):

If your lists have the same lenght:

```
c = []
for idx in range(len(a)):
    c.append(a[idx]+b[idx])
```

Not very elegant though.

Comment: The problem is that I deal with big lists with lots of rows and columns. So I can't use these kinds of methods where I need to address every element. But thanks anyway.

Comment: If you throw that in a loop ?

Comment: I tried `    a=[['1'],['2']]
    b=[['3'],['4']]
    c=[]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c[i] = [a[i] + b[i]] `
But it gives me 'List assignment index out of range'