# Calculate and add column in python

Tags: python, col

I think I have a fairly simple question for a python expert. With a lot of struggling I put together underneath code. I am opening an excel file, transforming it to a list of lists and adding a column to this list of lists. Now I want to rename and recalculate the rows of this added column. How do I script that I always take the last column of a list of lists, even though the number of columns could differ.

```
import xlrd
file_location = "path"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]
data = [x + [0] for x in data]
```

Comment: What do you mean by `adding a column to a list of lists`? Do you mean you add an element to the inner list?

Comment: I got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002415/how-can-i-add-an-additional-row-and-column-to-an-array 
He calls it adding a column. Not sure if that is exactly what I do but it appears to be what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a more easy and more flexible way of adjusting the values in the last column.

```
counter = 0
for list in data:
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == 1:
        value = 'Vrspng'
    else:
        value = counter
    list.append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function called `calculate_value` that takes a row and returns the value for that row, you could do it like this:

```
def calculate_value(row):
    # calculate it...
    return value

def add_calculated_column(rows, func):
    result_rows = []
    for row in rows:
        # create a new row to avoid changing the old data
        new_row = row + [func(row)]
        result_rows.append(new_row)
    return result_rows

data_with_column = add_calculated_column(data, calculate_value)
```

Comment: This looks like what I want. Thank you. Going to test it now.

Comment: Ok. This has helped a lot already. I am capable of recalculating a value in the last column. However, I want my first row to have a different value than the second row of the column. The first row being integer and the second row being a calculated value.